# Compile my RPi programs on my PC

Tags: cross-compilation

Since I got my RPi, I have been playing with it and I am really happy that I bought it!

I use various programs on it but it takes a long time to build them.
So I had an idea. What if I could build my programs on my quad-core PC, it will be a lot faster!? ^^

Is there a way to build my programs on Windows or Debian on my PC for my RPi ?

Comment: -You could try http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/ I guess. Maybe you can overclok this virtual achine, should give a good boost.

Comment: This might help: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1/40

Comment: QEMU looks easier to use than crosstools-ng, but I will keep it if I fail to use QEMU. Thank you Uwe Ziegenhagen and Jivings :-)

Comment: There's a ready-to-roll cross-compiler for the RPi available here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1144/4402

Comment: This is called cross-compilation, and, as @Jivings points out, has already been answered in the post that he linked.

Comment: Using qemu user emulation works, however...   it takes a little setting up (compiling your own qemu to get a more recent version works best).    I've found running on an i7, the speed was similar to running on a real pi.    Also, in the qemu emulator proper, I didn't manage to get SNP working, so was limited to 1 core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you, he explained it very nicely:
[Development environment raspberry cross compiler](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/)

Edit: Link is currently broken: [PDF Mirror](http://www.lab4inf.fh-muenster.de/lab4inf/docs/Embedded-Software/Eclipse_Cross_Development.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I downloaded the toolchains from the repo indicated in your article. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just gave an answer to a similar question here:

[Can I use my Ubuntu desktop to cross-compile the GO language environment for my Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/can-i-use-my-ubuntu-desktop-to-cross-compile-the-go-language-environment-for-my/4600#4600)

NB. I'm not Frepa ;)

To summarize, yes it is, but building a cross-compiler is not a trivial task for most people; I recently used [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to do it which A) made the procedure pretty painless, B) produced a c/c++ compiler that works to compile executables for the pi.

If you just want this to build *your own* stuff then I do recommend it *if* the caveats I mentioned there about use of autotools and pkg-config do not apply *or* you are willing to deal with the hassles to make that happen (dealing with those hassles *may* take you longer than just compiling on the pi, so...).

Crosstool-ng can produce a basic environment in which you can compile programs that rely on the standard libraries + POSIX threading (that's what I tested successfully).  Beyond that, you have to build any support libraries you use (sqlite, curl, ncurses, etc.) in that environment first too.

Answer (score 2):

You can build Raspberry Pi cross-compiler running on Windows by using MinGW, Cygwin and some patches from Raspbian repository, here is an instruction how to do it: http://www.gurucoding.com/en/rpi_cross_compiler/index.php

Comment: This is your site?